# Alteration of Rebol's SEND favouring To/CC/BCC fields for defining recipients

Tags: email, rebol, rebol2

I was looking for a way to better define email recipients along the lines of the To/CC/BCC convention. Although SYSTEM/STANDARD/EMAIL contains CC and BCC fields, they are not currently functional, see:

["How to Add Addresses to the BCC Field Using Rebol's Send Function"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33817146/292969)

Therefore in this solution, I've reorganised the SEND command to do my bidding based in part on this handy little answer:

["Sending BCC emails using an SMTP Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611044/292969) (by @eml)

**The SEND Function**

The key is collecting **ALL** recipient addresses from To/CC/BCC (and the ADDRESS function argument) for use with the SMTP `RCPT` command, then reformatting the To/CC fields and setting BCC to `none` before composing the header object. Preliminary tests seem to indicate this approach works.

(Also included here is the function uses SYSTEM/STANDARD/EMAIL as a base for the header object, so you only need pass a block/minimal object as an argument—this should preserve the 'copy part of the message for the subject line' feature)

```
send: func [
    {Send a message to an address (or block of addresses)} 
    address [email! block!] "An address or block of addresses" 
    message "Text of message. First line is subject." 
    /only "Send only one message to multiple addresses" 
    /header "Supply your own custom header" 
    header-obj [block! object!] "The header to use" 
    /attach "Attach file, files, or [.. [filename data]]" 
    files [file! block!] "The files to attach to the message" 
    /subject "Set the subject of the message" 
    subj "The subject line" 
    /show "Show all recipients in the TO field" 
    /local smtp-port boundary make-boundary tmp from
][
    make-boundary: does []

    if file? files [files: reduce [files]] 

    message: either string? message [copy message] [mold message]

    ; bases any custom object on SYSTEM/STANDARD/EMAIL
    header-obj: make system/standard/email any [
        header-obj
        [subject: any [subj copy/part message any [find message newline 50]]]
    ]

    if subject [header-obj/subject: subj]

    either none? from: any [
        header-obj/from
        header-obj/from: system/user/email
    ][
        net-error "Email header not set: no from address"
    ][
        if all [
            string? system/user/name
            not empty? system/user/name
        ][
            header-obj/from: rejoin [system/user/name " <" from ">"]
        ]
    ] 

    address: collect [
        foreach recipient compose [(address)][
            if email? recipient [keep recipient]
        ]
    ]

    if find [email! block!] type?/word header-obj/to [
        append address header-obj/to: collect [
            foreach recipient compose [(header-obj/to)][
                if email? recipient [keep recipient]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    header-obj/to: unless empty? address [
        rejoin remove collect [
            foreach recipient address: unique address [
                keep ", "
                keep recipient
            ]
        ]
    ]

    header-obj/cc: if find [email! block!] type?/word header-obj/cc [
        append address header-obj/cc: unique collect [
            foreach recipient compose [(header-obj/cc)][
                if email? recipient [keep recipient]
            ]
        ]

        unless empty? header-obj/cc [
            rejoin remove collect [
                foreach recipient unique header-obj/cc [
                    keep ", "
                    keep recipient
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    ; notes on BCC here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611044/292969

    if find [email! block!] type?/word header-obj/bcc [
        append address collect [
            foreach recipient compose [(header-obj/bcc)][
                if email? recipient [keep recipient]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    header-obj/bcc: none

    if empty? address: unique address [
        net-error "No recipients specified."
    ]

    if none? header-obj/date [
        header-obj/date: to-idate now
    ]

    if attach [
        boundary: rejoin ["--__REBOL--" system/product "--" system/version "--" checksum form now/precise "__"]
        header-obj/MIME-Version: "1.0"
        header-obj/content-type: join "multipart/mixed; boundary=" [{"} skip boundary 2 {"}]
        message: build-attach-body message files boundary
    ]

    smtp-port: open [scheme: 'esmtp]

    ; The use of BCC makes it so SHOW is somewhat redundant. Possibly ONLY too.

    ; either only [
        ; address: copy address
        ; remove-each value address [not email? :value]
    message: head insert insert tail net-utils/export header-obj newline message
    insert smtp-port reduce [from address message]
        ; probe reduce [from address message]

    ; ][
    ;   foreach addr address [
    ;       if email? addr [
    ;           if not show [insert clear header-obj/to addr]
    ;           tmp: head insert insert tail net-utils/export header-obj newline message
    ;           insert smtp-port reduce [from reduce [addr] tmp]
    ;       ]
    ;   ]
    ; ]

    close smtp-port
]
```

**Testing**

Testing requires credentials to access an ESMTP server per the first lines below:

```
; originator credentials
system/user/name: "Foo Bert"
system/user/email: foo@bar.com
system/schemes/default/host: "mail.server"
system/schemes/esmtp/user: "mail.server.user"
system/schemes/esmtp/pass: "mail.server.pass"
system/standard/email/content-type: "text/plain"

; trace/net on

send/header bar@foo.com "Message Content" [
    To: bar@foo.com ; redundant, but here for completeness
    CC: baz@foo.com
    BCC: baz@bar.com
    Subject: "A Test Email"
]
```

Replace addresses as necessary!

**Review**

I'm looking to ascertain if:

- The function works as advertised
- Whether this is the right approach (seems to be a more efficient use of an SMTP instance)
- I am overlooking any other design considerations
- As a bonus, this would make the /ONLY and /SHOW refinements redundant

Comment: The tags for this question are [being discussed on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6168/41243).

Answer (score 4):

As a sort of coarse suggestion I would say that you're over-refining and not dialecting enough.  Imagine if you said it was always arity-2...header and body.  But if the header is just an email assume it's the To address.

So these would be equivalent:

```
send bar@foo.com "Message content"

send [To: bar@foo.com] "Message content"
```

`/attach` makes sense as a refinement that might add a third section, because when I think of parameterization that does seem appropriate and it's also "in the right position".

```
send/attach bar@foo.com "See attached files" [%world-takeover.pdf %kittens.gif]
```

I would suggest though that the other refinements are too much, and should be perhaps slipstreamed into the header or body as `<tag>` instructions...something out-of-band.

This feels a bit like a "port scheme" for email when you frame it this way.

Comment: I have a dialect in mind, however this was just a case of cleaning up the original function.

Comment: I'd previously put thought of how to approach SEND in [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/297886/94356).